# Add warning if field is undefined before use in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, typescript2.0

I have this code:

```
  @Input() myUuid;
  private dcs: HistoryService;

  constructor(private hsf: HistoryServiceFactory) {
    console.log('my uuid:', this.myUuid.toString());
  }
```

TypeScript does not give a warning here, as far as I can tell:

[image]

but myUuid should always be undefined, since it will only be guaranteed to be initialized after `ngOnInit()` is fired. Would it be possible for TS to know this and display a (compilation) warning?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad - also, why does TS not complain when I don't give `myUuid` a type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update TypeScript to the latest version. 2.7 introduced exactly this functionality: checks for definite assignment.

This is documented at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html

Specifically:

> TypeScript 2.7 introduces a new flag called --strictPropertyInitialization. This flag performs checks to ensure that each instance property of a class gets initialized in the constructor body, or by a property initializer. For example

Make sure you are use `--strict`

Note that if you have properties that you *want* to leave uninitialized after construction, you will now need to mark them as optional (`property?`). This was always a good practice in such cases but is now enforced.

Comment: `strictNullChecks` may also be helpful.

Comment: Answers as good as these only occur when questions are as beautiful as OP

Comment: Make sure to understand the subtle differences between `property?: string` and `property: string | undefined`. They're not the same, and they're both valid depending upon the situation. The compiler will help send you in the right direction.